# Changing colour of sprite using enumeration

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Hi all a little bit stuck on this one, 
i'm hoping to colour the sprites added to the screen by enumerating through them by name (my first try at enumeration)so am pretty sure it will be something simple that i've missed - code is below
any help appreciated.

Adding sprite to layer:

```
for(int keyCount = 0; keyCount < ammountOfSprites; ++keyCount)
  //other code here....

    Star01 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Actions-rating-icon.png"];
    Star01.position = CGPointMake(-30,StarHeight);
    [MyLabel addChild:Star01];
    **Star01.name** = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Star01_%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dataFromArray]];
    NSLog(@"%@", Star01.name);
```

///the names log as:

```
Star01_Owl
Star02_Owl
Star03_Owl
```

inside of touches began

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

 //colour to add to the 
 UIColor *blackColour = [UIColor greenColor];


  //function takes sprite.names and enumerates them
  //name match those logged however dont work.
 [self changeStarScorestar01:@"Star01_Owl" star02:@"Star02_Owl" star03:@"Star03_Owl" colour:blackColour];
```

the later...

```
//function takes sprite.names and enumerates them
-(void)changeStarScorestar01:(NSString*)star01 star02:(NSString*)star02 star03:(NSString*)star03 colour:(UIColor*)Starcolour
{

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:star01 usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
   {

        NSLog(@"node.name isEqualToString:star01");
        SKSpriteNode *star01Found = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:star01];
    star01Found.color =Starcolour;
    star01Found.colorBlendFactor =1.0;

}
```

on testing it cant find the sprite, so I must be targeting the wrong object >< or something??

```
  [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:star01 usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
    {
        if ([node.name isEqualToString:star01])
        {
            NSLog(@"FOUND STAR");

        }}
```

Comment: So you have your sprites in an `SKNode` called `MyLabel`? Is `MyLabel` then added to the scene?  If so, then I believe you need to enumerate the children of `MyLabel`, not the scene

Comment: Knight0fDragon - it was indeed the problem - thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your sprites in an `SKNode` called `MyLabel`.

Then `MyLabel` is added to the scene.

You are now calling `enumerateChildNodesWithName` on the actual scene.

Unfortunately this function is not called enumerateDecendentNodesWithName, and does not take into effect grandchildren or great-grandchildren nodes.

Instead you need to enumerate through whatever node is the parent of the nodes you need to look for, in this case `MyLabel`.

```
 [MyLabelenumerateChildNodesWithName:star01 usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
 {
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:star01])
    {
        NSLog(@"FOUND STAR");
    }
 }];
```

Comment: Finished enumeratingSelf ThroughDecendentStagesOfInsanity  :) 
lesson learnt!

Thanks Knight0fDragon!

Comment: you could always write the enumerateDecendentNodesWithName extension function if you really wanted it, but I wouldn't recommend it. haha.